# Using tokens to extract information on a .csv file

Tags: c, csv, token

[lista.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xdfpvms5kij8hz6/lista.csv?dl=0)

I want to "tokenize" a file called "lista.csv", which consists of a list like this:

> ID(char), temperature(int), RH(char), time(long int), \n, ID, ...

and so on.

My goal is to separate these parameters and classifying them. In other words, extract them from the .csv file into a struct, where each component is a field (ID, temp, etc..)

The program I kind of made up is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct datos {
    char ID;  
    int temperatura;   
    char RH;  
    long int time;
};
struct datos sensor;

const char* getfield(char* linea)
{
    const char* tok;
    tok = strtok(linea, ","); 
    sensor.ID=tok;
    printf("ID sensor:%c",sensor.ID);
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    sensor.temperatura=atoi(tok);
    printf("temperatura sensor:%c",sensor.temperatura);
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    printf("RH sensor:%c",sensor.RH);
    sensor.RH=tok;
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    sensor.time=atoi(tok);
    printf("time sensor:%c",sensor.time);
    tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
}

int main()
{
    char buf[1024];
    FILE *p = fopen("lista.csv", "r");

    while (fgets(buf, 1024, p))
    {
        char* tmp = strdup(buf);
        getfield(tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

It seems that I do not understand how the `char` pointer `tok` works because I don't have positive results: The information stored in the struct cant be printed on the screen, a "?" sign appears. 
Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide an example input?

Comment: i uploaded the .csv file at the top

Comment: does this line compile? `sensor.ID=tok;`  `tok` is a `const char *` and `sensor.ID` is a `char`.  Are you sure you didn't mean `sensor.ID=*tok;` ?

Comment: Your `printf` [format specifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Type_field) are wrong.  You are using `%c` for everything but `%c` only applies for `char`.

Comment: it does compile. however, when i change the line into what you just said, it also compiles but returns invalid data instead of the "?" sign

Comment: you are either compiling without warnings or you are ignoring your warnings.  don't do that.

Comment: Thank to your comments it is working better now: I am using "*tok" instead of "tok" to fill the struct. I am also printing using the correct "%d" for ints, etc. However, it just prints the first digit of the number, for example in sensor.ID. I will try to fix that